# Android IDE issues

Tags: android, ide

is there a way to download ADT bundle classic and not android studio?.
because i have to publish a old project but importing to android studio í am having a little troubles with compatibility.
why google don´t let download ADT bundle anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still add the plug-in to Eclipse.

[here is the link to download the plug-in with instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)